# SDDM freezes when trying to switch user after upgrade from focal to jammy

Tags: kubuntu, xorg, login-screen, sddm

After kubuntu upgrade from focal to jammy when trying to switch user SDDM displays switch user screen but do not respond to keyboard or mouse, so it is impossible to switch. Before upgrade everything was OK.
What can I do with it?

```
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel WhiskeyLake-U GT2 [UHD Graphics 620] driver: i915 v: kernel
  Device-2: Cheng Uei Precision Industry (Foxlink) HP Wide Vision HD
    Integrated Webcam
    type: USB driver: uvcvideo
  Display: server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.3 driver: X: loaded: modesetting
    unloaded: fbdev,vesa gpu: i915 resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz
  OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel UHD Graphics 620 (WHL GT2)
    v: 4.6 Mesa 22.0.5
```